# pass ngKeyUp function into directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I’ve got a directive/template that contains an input field.

The input field has an ngKeyup and an ngModel.

I want the ngKeyup function to be passed into the directive. The ngKeyup on the input field within the directive/template should invoke this function.

This plunker shows option 1 and option 2 http://plnkr.co/edit/kN8mitdG6pK5GNqGzYw5?p=preview

Option one is simplest and partially works, the function is simply passed in by '=', the directive references it in the ngKeyUp attribute

**Directive**

```
ngApp.directive("searchField", ['$parse',function ($parse) {

return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        myKeyUp: '=',
```

**Template**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-keyup="myKeyUp" />
```

This partially works, but the $event object is not passed.

In option two the directive receives the function from the controller as an '&', tries to $parse it and invoke it. This simply isn't working for me but I'm not very familiar with $parse.

ngKeyup can receive any parameters e.g. ng-keyup(a,b,c,$index,$event)

A key point/requirement is that this directive should be the same i.e. myKeyUp should be capable of accepting any parameters.

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

It has to be '&' in scope, as it allows you to pass the function reference.

and what you have to do in the template is:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-keyup="myKeyUp($event)" />
```

UPDATE: 
Here is another approach that you could take: http://goo.gl/a27JrX

Comment: Thanks Aganglada but the $event is still undefined: http://plnkr.co/edit/bvBrZR43vTD62e6NIYrE?p=preview If you look at the console, the log shows 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a really simple solution.

**Quote from question**

> I want the ngKeyup function to be passed into the directive. The ngKeyup on the input field within the directive/template should invoke this function.

Turns out the div can simply have the ng-keyup attribute, it doesn't have to be on the input field. 
This completely solves the problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xTigcDaSLpL9pvRtfY5J?p=preview

Now the directive takes only the model as a parameter. The ngKeyup is outside the directive.

```
ngApp.directive("searchField", ['$parse',function ($parse) {

return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        model: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'searchFieldTemplate',
    replace: true,
    controller: ['$scope','$attrs', function ($scope, $attrs) {

    }]
  };

}]);
```

And the template is now only concerned with the model

```
<div class="searchField">
<h4>Template</h4>
  (observe the console)
<div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="model" />
</div>
```

That actually makes allot of since when you think about it....